# Does this sequence of H\"older functions have a limit?

Tags: real-analysis, fa.functional-analysis

Let $\left\{\alpha_{n}\right\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ a sequence of positive real numbers with 
$$\alpha_{n}\in (0,1)\quad \textrm{and}\quad \alpha_{n}>\alpha_{n+1}$$
Moreover suppose 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\alpha_{n}=\bar{\alpha}>0$$
Now let $\left\{f_{n}\right\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ a  family of functions with  $f_{n}\in C^{0,\alpha_{n}}(B_{1})$ and suppose there exist $C$ independent of $n$ s.t. for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$
$$\left\|f_{n}\right\|_{C^{0,\alpha_{n}}(B_{1})}\leq C$$
Does exist a $C^{0,\frac{\bar{\alpha}}{2}}$-convergent subsequence of $\left\{ f_{n} \right\}_{n}$ with a limit  $\bar{f}\in C^{0,\frac{\bar{\alpha}}{2}}(B_{1})$?
I'd say yes, but i wonder if there are subtleties i don't see...

Comment: obviously homework

Comment: Why wouldn't you remove the "$4,$" in all the exponents?

Comment: If this isn't homework, why do you need the solution?

Comment: As i said in the post i'm quite sure that the limit exists at least continuous by Ascoli-Arzela theorem, for Holder continuity i'm also quite sure, i embed $C^{0,\alpha_{n}}$ in $C^{0,\frac{3\bar{\alpha}}{4}}$, since the embedding is bounded i have that the sequence of $f_{n}$ is bounded and so i can extract a convergent subsequence in $C^{0,\frac{\bar{\alpha}}{2}}$... I was wondering if it is correct or there is some subtlety i don't see... that's all. 